# how to debug invalid subscript type 'integer' error in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the code in [R: extract maximum value in vector under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591122/r-extract-maximum-value-in-vector-under-certain-conditions) but I keep getting the error

```
Error in list(id.2 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  : 
  invalid subscript type 'integer'
```

The code is the following:

```
require(dplyr)
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "id    name    year    job    job2 cumu_job2
1   Jane    1980    Worker  0   0
1   Jane    1981    Manager 1   1
1   Jane    1982    Sales   0   0
1   Jane    1983    Sales   0   0
1   Jane    1984    Manager 1   1
1   Jane    1985    Manager 1   2
1   Jane    1986    Boss    0   0
2   Bob     1985    Worker  0   0
2   Bob     1986    Sales   0   0
2   Bob     1987    Manager 1   1
2   Bob     1988    Manager 1   2
2   Bob     1989    Boss    0   0
3   Jill    1989    Worker  0   0
3   Jill    1990    Boss    0   0")

dat %.%
  group_by(id) %.%
  mutate(
    all_jobs = sum(unique(job) %in% c("Sales","Manager","Boss")),
    cumu_max = max(cumu_job2)
  ) %.%
  filter(all_jobs == 3, job %in% c("Sales","Boss"))

Source: local data frame [5 x 8]
Groups: id

  id name year   job job2 cumu_job2 all_jobs cumu_max
1  1 Jane 1982 Sales    0         0        3        2
2  1 Jane 1983 Sales    0         0        3        2
3  1 Jane 1986  Boss    0         0        3        2
4  2  Bob 1986 Sales    0         0        3        2
5  2  Bob 1989  Boss    0         0        3        2
```

Comment: Did you make sure that copypasting didn't introduce end-of-line chars which might disrupt the code flow?

Comment: Your example works fine for me as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sample code works for me, too. But I have found that I can repro a similar error if I attempt this:

```
dat %.%
 group_by(dat$id) %.%
 mutate(
     all_jobs = sum(unique(job) %in% c("Sales","Manager","Boss")),
     cumu_max = max(cumu_job2)
 ) %.%
 filter(all_jobs == 3, job %in% c("Sales","Boss"))
```

that is, if I type "group_by(dat$id)" instead of "group_by(id)"

Comment: I've had the same error and able to correct it like @schnee did. any other way around this (I'd like to be able to keep my object organized into a list the way they are)

Answer (score 6):

**Bug**

The sample code works for me as well. However as schnee mentioned, you can create a similar error by replacing group_by(id) by group_by(dat$id). Reproducible code:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(x=c('A','A','B','B'), y=c('A','B','C','D'), val = 1:4)
dat2 <- data.frame(val = 1:4)
dat_group <- data.frame(x=c('A','A','B','B'))

# invalid subscript type 'integer'
dat1 %>%
  group_by(dat1$x) %>%
  mutate(y = sum(unique(y) %in% c("A","B","C")))

# invalid subscript type 'list'
dat2 %>%
  group_by(dat_group$x) %>%
  mutate(y = sum(unique(y) %in% c("A","B","C")))
```

While the first one is usually just a typo (you can replace dat$x with x), the second one could be a valid use case (although I would recommend a join to make it cleaner).

**Solution**

The dplyr package doesn't like the usage of '$'. Try instead using '[', e.g.:

```
dat1[,'x']
```

Quoting the variable also works:

```
dat1$'x'
```

Full code:

```
dat1 %>%
  group_by(dat1[,'x']) %>%
  mutate(y = sum(unique(y) %in% c("A","B","C")))

dat1 %>%
  group_by(dat1$'x') %>%
  mutate(y = sum(unique(y) %in% c("A","B","C")))
```

See also https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/433 or https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1554